# How to include blog title into wp_blogs table?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wpmu

I wanted to insert the blog title into `wp_blogs` table upon signup. I can't find on the `wp-signup.php` file where should i do the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify a core file. You should use an appropriate hook for this.
Take a look at [Plugin API/Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for more details. I think [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) will do the job